# Error during pylucene installation in mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pylucene

I am trying to install pylucene to mac terminal

I tried the instructions on the following link:

http://macappstore.org/pylucene/

and when I installed, I get the following error

> Error: No available formula with the name "pylucene"
>   ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...   Error: No similarly named formulae found.
>   ==> Searching taps...   Error: No formulae found in taps.

Could anyone please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: pylucene seems to be a very old app see [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/4968) for why it’s not in homebrew.

Comment: Thanks. I did see the link but could not figure out how to go about it. am new to mac as well. So, how do I otherwise install pylucene in mac.

Comment: You can see that pylucene has not been updated in over 3 years... If _anybody_ knew how to build it, it would be on homebrew. I suggest you try to find an alternative for pylucene at the time being.